# libQt5: no version information available

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-22.04

I was trying to install barrier KVM on my Ubuntu 22.04, and couldn't get through.
I installed barrier via

`sudo apt install barrier`
and when I tried to launch the program, the error message as below showed up.

```
barrier: /opt/MarkAny/libs/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by barrier)
barrier: /opt/MarkAny/libs/libQt5Widgets.so.5: no version information available (required by barrier)
barrier: symbol lookup error: barrier: undefined symbol: _ZNK11QPushButton9hitButtonERK6QPoint, version Qt_5
```

I tried googling it around but couldn't find the fix for this matter.
I've tried installing all kinds of qt5-xxx packages, reinstalling but nothing helped.

I've seen several answers looking something like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/QT/gcc_64/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/pe/qtbase/lib':$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

seems like I have to make some kind of link to qt5,
but I'm not sure of 1) how to find the path to my qt package, 2) which qt package I would have to link, (since I now have a lot of packages related to Qt5), and 3) which of the two solutions above is the correct one to follow. The two seem to be similar, but quite different in path (e.g. gcc_64 vs /home/pe ...).

and I'm wondering what the purpose of this Qt5 package is...?